# Название специальной крышки на таре

Tags: названия

Имеет ли эта крышка какое-то специальное название?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Я бы её назвал крышкой-мельницей.

Comment: Как тогда называть съёмную часть крышки мельницы, открывающую доступ к уже молотому продукту, - "крышкой крышки-мельницы"? У съёмной части больше оснований именоваться "крышкой" вместилища, чем у несъёмной (несъёмная крышка - понятие несколько парадоксальное, это ближе к "заглушке").